# Php Header redirects, but doesnt echo after that

Tags: php

It redirects them back to the homepage but I want it to also display a box.

```
if($m->send()){
header('Location:http://blankwebsite.com/');
echo '<script>
alert("Your Quote Request has been submitted!");
</script>';

}
else{
echo $m->ErrorInfo;
}`
```

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't make sense.  The header returns a redirect response to the client, which contains no body.  (Or even if it does, the browser will just ignore the body.)  Redirect *or* display content, not both.

Comment: Maybe this is what you want: [displaying a message after redirecting the user to another web page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12249906/4577762) (<- and this question also has a possible duplicate)

Comment: To try clearing up the confusion wich was my bad. This part of my script, this script is activated by someone filling out a form and submitting it, I want it to redirect them back to the page where they filled out the form and then notify them that it was sent successfully. If i didn't have a redirect it would keep them on script.php (a blank page) and have a pop up saying it was sent successfully. Sorry for the confusion hope this helps.

Comment: When i had the 2 flipped it would display the notification successfully but then bring me to script.php and show an error "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by"

Comment: @CodyCayetano Please consider editing your question instead of commenting for clarity. Also try adding as much details as you can to have more detailled and accurate answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the html in a session variable, display it after redirect and empty the session variable like a flash message at script start up.

```
if($m->send()){

    $_SESSION['redirectMessage'] = base64_encode(utf8_encode('<script>alert("Your Quote Request has been submitted!");</script>'));

    header('Location:http://blankwebsite.com/');
}
else{
     echo $m->ErrorInfo;
}
```

On new page request or redirect:

```
 if isset($_SESSION['redirectMessage']) {
     echo htmlentities(base64_decode($_SESSION['redirectMessage']), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
      $_SESSION['redirectMessage'] = null;
  }
```

This solution uses sessions, so do make sure session_start() is called at the top of the script.