# Making a message box appear after being returned back to a login page

Tags: php, html

I am creating a website for my Computer Science project.

I am also new to PHP/HTML coding.

Basically, the idea is this. I have a login page which either takes you into the website or doesn't let you in. However, I want the website to tell the user that the username/pass isn't correct when the get rejected.

Here is the login page:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
<body>
<center>
<h1 style="font-size:70px;">FitnessHub<h1>
<p>Enter Username & Password to get started</P>

<form action="Welcome.php" method="post">

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" style="width:400px;height:30px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" style="width:400px;height:30px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Login" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
<br>



</form>
<img src="fitnesshub.png" alt="logo" style="width:400px;height=300px;">





</center>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the welcoming page when you successfully login:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
<body>


<h1> Hello <?php echo $_REQUEST[username] ?> </h1>

<p style="Font-Size:15px;">FitnessCenter can be used to book customers into multiple services<br>
Use the buttons to start using the database 
</p>

<?php
$db = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "root", "fitnessbooking");
$query= $db->query("select Username from users where Username = '$_POST[username]' and Pass = '$_POST[password]'");

if ($query->num_rows ==1){
echo "";
}
else {
header("Location: http://localhost/pages/login.php");

    exit;
}
?>





</body>
</html>
```

As I said, I am no expert at website stuff so please try to explain things in a way I can understand!

Thanks

Comment: [displaying a message after redirecting the user to another web page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249906/displaying-a-message-after-redirecting-the-user-to-another-web-page)

Comment: instead of the form posting to a welcome page right away, create another php page that it will post to, then check the credentials and if they are bad, reject it or if good then send it to the welcome.php

Answer (score 0):

In the redirection add ?fail=1 to pass the parameter

```
header("Location: http://localhost/pages/login.php?fail=1");
```

In the login page add

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_GET['fail']) && $_GET['fail'] == 1 )
    {

         echo "Try again:)";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do all things in the login page like this.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['auth'])){
    header('Location: logged_in.php');
    die();
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $db = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "root", "fitnessbooking");
    if ($db->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $stmt = $db->prepare('select Username from users where Username = ? and Pass = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
        $_SESSION['auth'] = true;
        header('Location: logged_in.php');
        die();
    }
    else{
        $error_message = "Username Or password are invalid";
    }
}

 ?>


<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
<body>
    <center> 
        <h1 style="font-size:70px;">FitnessHub<h1>
        <p>Enter Username & Password to get started</P>


        <?php 
            //Display the error message
            if (isset($error_message)){
                echo "<p><strong>$error_message</strong></p>"
            }
        ?>
        <form action="Welcome.php" method="post">

            <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" style="width:400px;height:30px;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" style="width:400px;height:30px;"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>

            <input type="submit" value="Login" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
            <br>



        </form>
        <img src="fitnesshub.png" alt="logo" style="width:400px;height=300px;">





    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

The other page leave like that:

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['auth'])){
    die('Access denied');
}

<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
<body>


<h1> Hello User </h1>

<p style="Font-Size:15px;">FitnessCenter can be used to book customers into multiple services<br>
Use the buttons to start using the database 
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want, store the username in the session to have it usable.

Answer (score -2):

Use this sample.

```
    <html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
<body>
<center>


<?php if((!empty($_GET['login'] )&& ($_GET['login'] == 'false')): ?>
<p>username or password incorrect</P>
<?php  endif;?>


<h1 style="font-size:70px;">FitnessHub<h1>
<p>Enter Username & Password to get started</P>

<form action="Welcome.php" method="post">

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" style="width:400px;height:30px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" style="width:400px;height:30px;"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Login" style="width:100px;height:30px;">
<br>



</form>
<img src="fitnesshub.png" alt="logo" style="width:400px;height=300px;">





</center>
</body>
</html>
```

And your wellcome page is.

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
<body>


<h1> Hello <?php echo $_REQUEST[username] ?> </h1>

<p style="Font-Size:15px;">FitnessCenter can be used to book customers into multiple services<br>
Use the buttons to start using the database 
</p>

<?php
$db = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "root", "fitnessbooking");
$query= $db->query("select Username from users where Username = '$_POST[username]' and Pass = '$_POST[password]'");

if ($query->num_rows ==1){
echo "";
}
else {
    header("Location: http://localhost/pages/login.php?login=false");

    exit;
}
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this out!!