# PHP echo in a HTML Page

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a contact.**html** page I have a form on.  The form action goes to .php page to handle the email, nothing special. On that page I have:

```
<?php
function check_input($data)
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}

$FirstName = check_input($_REQUEST['FirstName']);
$LastName = check_input($_REQUEST['LastName']);
$email = check_input($_REQUEST['email']);
$phone = check_input($_REQUEST['phone']);
$message = check_input($_REQUEST['message']);
$human = check_input($_REQUEST['human']);
$webpackage = check_input($_REQUEST['webpackage']);
$webdesign = check_input($_REQUEST['webdesign']);
$customdesign = check_input($_REQUEST['customdesign']);

if ($human == 5) {

$to = "****.com";
$subject = "From ****";

$body = " From: $FirstName  $LastName\n\n E-Mail: $email\n\n Phone:     $phone\n\n Message:\n\n $message\n\n Web Package:$webpackage\n\n Web     Design:$webdesign\n\n Custom Design:$customdesign";


mail ($to, $subject, $body);
header('location: index.html');
}
else {
$result="<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">Sorry there was an error sending     your message. Please go back and check your anti-spam answer</div>";
}

?>
```

I have a simple box that equals 5 that I am checking value for.  This works and email sent with all info.  **BUT** if not equal to 5 is where the problem starts. The page goes to my `action.php` page and is blank.

My html on the `contact.html` page is:

```
    <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <?php echo($result); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Using this to get to my `action.php` page through form. Everything else is .html:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" id="contact-form" method="post" action="/action.php">
```

Is there a way to do this? I have a work around where I just `echo` the error from the `.php` page. This works if `!=5` but not exactly what I want to do.  As you may tell, I am not PHP literate.

Comment: Maybe some of the code you left out is getting an error and the script stops.

Comment: What do you mean by "The page goes to my .php page"? How are you going from the page that handles the email to the page that displays the DIV?

Comment: I think you need to post the whole script, it's impossible to tell what you're really doing from the snippets you've given.

Comment: Hopefully edited to help @Barmar.  My error, I assume everyone knows what I am thinking sometimes. Posting form to action.php above.  Works great when correct answer of 5 is given.  Its the else that will not work.

Comment: `My html on the contact.html page is:` So.... why does your html page contain PHP code?

Comment: Change your page name to `contact.php`. It will now be able to execute embedded PHP code. With the `.html` extension, your web server will treat it as a static page and not execute any embedded code.

Comment: I still don't understand how the PHP that processes the form is related to the HTML later. Variables don't persist between different pages, except for session variables in `$_SESSION`. So unless they're the same page, `$result` will be empty.

Comment: Steve your flow of events is not clear. Assuming user enters 5 or whatever, in the input and submits, the page has to go to action.php (which seems to be in the root...due to the  /). After that there doesn't seem to be a connection to the HTML you have posted.... like maybe a header redirect. Maybe you want to do a header redirect back to contact page if the $human is not 5 (if the result div is in contact page)

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable in the `$_SESSION[]` array, and in your "else" section use `Header()` to redirect to a page where you display the value you stored.

See example in this other answered question:

[displaying a message after redirecting the user to another web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12249906/displaying-a-message-after-redirecting-the-user-to-another-web-page)

Answer (score 0):

1. Update your else part with following code :

   ```
    } else {
        header('location: contact.html?status=error');
    }
   ```
2. Now check if get method is set on your contact.html page. if yes than set and display your $result value.

   ```
   <?php 
     if(isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status']=='error' ) { 

     $result="<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">Sorry there was an error sending     your message. Please go back and check your anti-spam answer</div>";           

   } ?>
   ```
3. on contact.html check if $result has value and print it :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a redirect towards contact.html in your action.php like this

```
else {
$result="Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please go back and check your anti-spam answer"; 
$result=str_replace(" ","%20",$result);
header('location: contact.html?result=$result'); 
}
```

And then get the result in contact.html with GET

```
$result= $_GET['result'];
```

Ideally do the html mark up for result in the destination Contact.html page after you receive the result. That eliminates the nuances of passing html over http